# Column level security in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a list (**Employee Details**) having six columns

- ID
- Name
- Address
- department
- Passport Number
- Mobile Number.

Now, for security purpose I want to hide some columns 
(**ex-Passport Number, Mobile Number**) for specific group of people. How can we achieve this?

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to achieve this at view level. Follow these steps.

- Create different view based on your requirement. Remove unwanted
  columns from view.
- Go to site settings --> People and Group --> Groups --> New --> New Group.
- Give the name and choose the permission level for group members . Click OK.
- Open your group --> new --> add users to this group.
- Go back to your list.
- Click on edit page and go to your web part properties. 
  [image]
- Go to Advanced.

[image]

- In Target Audiences, select the person or group. Click OK. Now, only the persons in target audiences will be able to see that view.
- Once verified, Publish the page.

Comment: A possible issue is that this is audience targeting but NOT security. Everyone still has access to the "hidden" columns e.g. by switching views.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box. You need to use 3rd Party tools or code you own solution. There are very good articles out there. One example is

[Column Level Security in SharePoint](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Dressel-Gogolowicz-wss-security)

[How to: Create a Custom Field Type and Field Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417414(v=office.12).aspx)

You need to create a Custom Field Type which can be security trimmed within your code.